# What is the mathematical symbol for the unique values of union of two sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let's say you have two sets: `A=[875 900 925 950 975 1000]` and `B=[825 850 875 900 925 950]`. You'd like find the set of unique elements after the union sets `A` and `B`. In Matlab you can use the [unique function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and obtain the result:

```
A=[875 900 925 950 975 1000];
B=[825 850 875 900 925 950];
C=unique([A,B]);
>> C
C =
825 850 875 900 925 950 975 1000
```

How to write the **unique function** in the mathematical notation?

**update.**

I have tried: $A \bigcup B = \{x: (x \in A \vee x \in B) \}.$
In Matlab the union function gives the same result:

```
C = union(A,B)
C =
 825 850 875 900 925 950 975 1000
```

Comment: Do you mean to ask what the notation for $A \cup B - A \cap B$ is?

Comment: @bof, thanks, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited answer**: after running the OP's example in MATLAB, it appears that the object of interest simply is 
$$
A\cup B.
$$
e.g. with `A` and `B` as specified, `unique([A, B])` yields

`825         850         875         900         925         950         975         1000`

Comment: @bof It cannot be $A\cup B$ because the OP clarifies that the object of interest is $A\cup B$ minus some adjustment.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I ran OP's example in MATLAB and I confirm that you both are right.

Comment: @bof Thank you. Please see edit.